# Joining an array of keys to a hash with key value pairs like excel vlookup

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, hashmap

I've got an unsorted array of keys like this:

```
keys = ["ccc", "ddd", "ggg", "aaa", "bbb"]
```

and a hash

```
hash = {"ddd" => 4, "aaa" => 1, "bbb" => 2, "eee" => 5, "fff" => 6}
```

I'd like to join these two data structures to return a hash in the original order of keys to the first keys:

```
{"ccc" => nil, "ddd" => 4, "ggg" => nil, "aaa" => 1, "bbb" => 2}
```

Items NOT in the hash (like "ggg") should return nil.
This is analogous to the "v-lookup" function in excel.
this is in ruby. Thanks!

Comment: In your expected hash, why is "ccc" 3 and not nil? Why is "ddd" 4 and not 3?

Comment: because i wrote this question without ample caffeine. should be corrected now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cryptic:

```
Hash[keys.zip(hash.values_at *keys)]
```

Or a bit longer, a bit less cryptic:

```
keys.map.with_object({}) {|key, memo| memo[key] = hash[key]}
```

Comment: +1 for the functional solution. I wouldn't call it cryptic, it describes exactly what it's doing.

Comment: what if instead of an Hash, i have an array of hash like this: [{"ddd"=>4}, {"aaa"} => 1 ...]  does this solution still work?

Comment: Why would you have such a stupid data structure? Just map it to the `keys` array.

Comment: this is the data structure returned to me in Mysql2::Result

Comment: `result.map {|hash| hash.first.first}`

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I've thrown up another question which is very similar, but closer to my actual data set http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983741/looking-up-an-array-of-keys-on-an-array-of-hashes-in-ruby-like-excel-vlookup