# Looking up an array of keys on an array of hashes in ruby like excel vlookup

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, hashmap

This post is very similar to my previous one, but the data structures are different here:
[Joining an array of keys to a hash with key value pairs like excel vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981671/joining-an-array-of-keys-to-a-hash-with-key-value-pairs-like-excel-vlookup)

My data from my Mysql2::Result comes back like this array of hashes:

```
data = [{"isbn" => "1234", "title"=>"apple"},{"isbn" => "5678", "title"=>"banana"},{"isbn" => "2121", "title"=>"car"}]
```

And my original list of isbns that I would like to compare is this array:

```
isbns = ["1234","2121", "5454", "5678"]
```

I'm seeking a function which uses the isbns array and returns a result like this:

```
result = [{"isbn"=>"1234","title"=>"apple"}, {"isbn"=> "2121", "title"=>"car"}, nil, {"isbn"=>"5678","title"=>"banana"}]
```

The "driving" array is the isbns... imagine doing a vlookup from isbns to data ... any items that are not in data, but in isbns should return nil. The original order of isbns should be returned, and the return data should be an array of hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
isbns.map { |isbn| data.find { |h| h["isbn"] == isbn} }
#=> [{"isbn"=>"1234", "title"=>"apple"}, {"isbn"=>"2121", "title"=>"car"}, nil, {"isbn"=>"5678", "title"=>"banana"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

@Michael Kohl's answer is succinct and correct. However if these data sets are big, it's inefficient O(n*m/2). An alternative is to transform the data vector into a hash in O(m) then do the map in O(n) for a runtime of O(n+m).

```
data_lookup = data.inject({}) {|m,v| m[v["isbn"]] = v; m} # O(data.size)
result = isbns.map { |isbn| data_lookup[isbn] }           # O(isbns.size)
```

If your data and isbn collections were of size 1000 each, this would be faster by a factor of 250.

Comment: oh damn this is college comp sci coming back to bite me in the bum...appreciate the suggestion, i'll surely give it a try

Comment: On 1000 records, your call took 0.008449514, the first call took 0.234835044 s

Comment: @hagope that pretty closely matches my estimate based on the big-O analysis.  Not a huge problem if you only run this calculation occasionally (though 235ms is a substantial delay for a single web request). If you had substantial scale and needed to do this calculation 500 times/sec, the fast version could manage that with one common four-core processor, the slow one would require 10 12-core servers to keep up.

Comment: I always go for code clarity first, you can optimize once something is proven slow. Also there's no mention of Rails, so I don't know where the speed of web requests came from in this discussion. :-) Anyway, +1.

Comment: @MichaelKohl no complaints about [clarity over efficiency](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), I was just adding a BTW. s/web request/interaction/ if you like, Rails isn't the only thing that computes http responses in ruby and the web is not the only context in which a quarter-second delay may annoy a user.

Comment: Sure, personally I do more Sinatra than Rails too, but a lot of the questions tagged Ruby on here are actually about Rails. As I said, your comment adds something valuable to the discussion, that's why I upvoted it.